# How to set a button onclick event and link to Thymeleaf controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to write some code where, once the user clicks a button, it will do some set of code in my Thymeleaf controller class. I tried looking on other various code found here on stackoverflow, however, I was not able to find a proper solution. The error I get is that the code will not print out the desired statement.

**Code:**

```
<button type="button" th:onclick="doStuffMethod()"> Hello</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
    public void doStuffMethod() {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, `th:onclick` is to call a javascript function, not controller.

Comment: @LHCHIN Thanks for answers back... I believe so to. However, my goal is when a button is clicked it tells Java to connect to my SQL DB. If you have any other ways for this approach, please I would like your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way can achieve this by following 2 steps:

**Step 1:** Make `doStuffMethod` to be visited with `/do-stuff`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/do-stuff")
public void doStuffMethod() {
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

**Step 2:** Use `window.location.href` to visit `/do-stuff`

```
<button type="button" th:onclick="|window.location.href='/do-stuff'|">Hello</button>
```

All above this can invoke your `doStuffMethod()` successfully after pressing the button, but it is going to throw some exception due to no template called `do-stuff`.
Therefore, a better way is to create a template called `doStuff.html` and return it's name as string in `doStuffMethod()`.

**doStuff.html**

```
<h1>Success</h1>
```

And modify your controller as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/do-stuff")
public String doStuffMethod() {
    System.out.println("Success");
    return "doStuff";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , for your suggestion, though when I call the method and it throws the doStuff.html. Does it just show a blank page with success, or is there a way I can ignore showing the page and just stay on the current one?

Comment: @kane01 Sure! You can return the template name of current page instead.

Comment: @kane01 Hi, if my post solved the problem, please accept it as answer, thanks!